# C++ Random number generator apparent malfunction: am I unlucky?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, random

I wanted to try the C++ random number generator but couldn't seem to obtain very satisfying results. For example here is an attempt among others to create a random string of characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

std::string f(unsigned int n){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis025(0, 25);
    std::mt19937 gen_mt(n);
    std::string str(5, '\0');
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        str[i] = (char)('a' + dis025(gen_mt));
    return str;
}
int g(unsigned int n, int m){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, m);
    std::mt19937 gen_mt(n);
    return dis(gen_mt);
}
int main() {
    std::string s = f(g(106175305, 40000000)) + " " + f(g(53718209, 40000000));
    std::cout << "Random string: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

[Link to Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7c601d4184a9b95).

(I had to use the `f(g())` trick so that it stops shouting insults.)
It is quite annoying and I doubt that is the desired behavior. But somehow I am helpless to prevent it, it keeps happening, again...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

std::string fx(unsigned int n, int m){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, m);
    std::mt19937 gen_mt(n);
    std::string str(6, '\0');
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        str[i] = (char)('.' + dis(gen_mt));
    return str;
}
int g(unsigned int n, int m){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, m);
    std::mt19937 gen_mt(n);
    return dis(gen_mt);
}
int main() {
    std::string s1 = fx(g(66730461, 90000000) + 400000000, 33) + "/" + fx(g(28989020, 90000000) * 10, 43);
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fbc901247b5cab2).
...and again.

```
int main() {
    std::string s2 = fx(g(66730461, 90000000) + 400000000, 33) + "/" + fx(g(81141643, 90000000) + 100000000, 43);
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

Do you often meet that kind of problem? or am I especially unlucky?

Comment: What's the goal here? Unpredictably random characters in a specific range, or repeatably random strings based on a seed?

Comment: The same algorithms run on the same inputs tend to provide the same results.

Comment: @tadman I would like repeatably random strings, so I tried various "random" seeds.

Comment: You should only need one random seed, not two or three, so it's unclear what your extra arguments do. Seeding `gen_mt` should be sufficient.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this question appears to be a joke: @Georg: I am afraid to say, you are incredibly unlucky, because when I use any seed values other than yours, I get random strings (like `"yrsfs vkmhd"`) instead of `hello world` :)

Comment: @tadman I do seed `gen_mt`. Trying not to give it too straightforward a seed, though, so I use some (pseudo) random there too.

Comment: There's no point in randomly seeding a random number generator to generate a random seed for another generator. The seed itself is fixed, the second stage output is fixed too.

Comment: @ContinuousLoad I get "tzsgb frnho" and "JCK@67/GP.=D5" for the first two examples.

Comment: @tadman Very interesting. I thought using `mt19937` (instead of `default_random_engine`) would make the code portable.

Comment: @Georg For what it's worth, those two programs both produce identical results when run repeatedly.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, wrong word, I now edited my comment above.

Comment: It's portable in that it compiles for me (`clang` on macOS) but I'm not sure that the random number generator is required to produce *identical* results on different platforms.

Comment: @tadman: On my system, I get these results for all three examples, in order: "hello world", "GOO.GL/8LFD4C", "GOO.GL/Y64ADE". There is an awful lot of information present in those "random" strings!

Comment: @ContinuousLoad It looks like someone's chosen random seeds that produce those output values but only on particular generator implementations. Clever, but not portable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question in the slightest.

Comment: This question is about 165 days late. (Or 200 days early. Your pick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My sad friend, I must inform you that in all my life I have never encountered a programmer with as poor luck as you have. The chances of a random string generator creating human-readable output is one in a million, but you managed to do it three times in a row (one in a trillion?)

In all honesty, the trick was quite clever. May your future endeavors be more predictable :)

*(Future readers: The results were generated using hand-picked pseudo-random seed values that happened to output specific strings, like "hello world", etc... Check out the comments on the question for more info)*

Comment: I don't have a source for MT, but for PCG it's really easy http://www.pcg-random.org/party-tricks.html and MT sucks anyway